Average size of a group
Question: There are 50 guests at a party and they are making groups for a game. To do this they each write their name on a piece of paper and put it into a hat. One by one, each guest picks a name from the hat. Each guest will be a part of a group with the guest they pulled the name out of from the hat. If a guest pulls out their own name, they are in a group all by themselves. If Guest A pulls out Guest B's name, Guest B pulls out Guest C's name, and Guest C pulls out Guest A's name, they are all a part of the same closed group and no one else will be able to join them. What is the average size of a group?
I am struggling with this question. My initial idea was to use the definition of expectation and count the average subset size from a group of 50,i.e. the average group size given we have only 1 group being formed is 50, the average group size given 2 groups are formed is 25, the average group size given 3 groups are formed is 50/3, etc. However this seems complicated and I was wondering if anyone could come up with a better method?
One approach I had was recursion i.e. average group size for 50 people = average group size for 49 people + $\frac{1}{50}$. But I don't think this is correct?

The notion of "average size of a group" is ambiguous. You can count the size of the group in two different ways. (A) Choose one of the several groups at random, and count its size. (B) Choose a random person, then count the size of the group containing that person. Due to size-biasing, the answer for (A) is smaller than that for (B). Which version are you asking about?

I don't know the question didn't specify

The notion of "average size of a group" is ambiguous. You can count the size of the group in two different ways.

Choose one of the several groups at random, and count its size.

Choose a random person, then count the size of the group containing that person.


Size of a random group
If there are $k$ groups, then the average size of a group is $\frac {50}k$. Letting ${n\brack k}$ denote the Stirling numbers of the first kind, the probability that a random permutation of $50$ people consists of $k$ groups is $\frac1{50!}{50\brack k}$. Therefore, the answer to this question is
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{50} \frac {50}k\cdot\frac1{50!}{50\brack k}\approx 13.32.
$$
Size of the group containing a particular person
Pick a random person, call them Alice. It turns out that the size of the group containing Alice is equally likely to be any number between $1$ and $50$. To see this, for each $k\in \{1,\dots,50\}$, count the number of permutations where Alice is in a cycle of length $k$. There are $\binom {49}{k-1}$ ways to choose the $k$ other people in the cycle, then $(k-1)!$ ways to choose a cyclic ordering for the cycle, and finally $(50-k)!$ ways to permute the remaining people. Therefore, the probability of being in a cycle of length $k$ is
$$
\frac{\binom{49}{k-1}\cdot (k-1)!\cdot (50-k)!}{50!}=\frac1{50}.
$$
This is true for all $k$, so the size of Alice's group is uniformly random between $1$ and $50$. The expected size of such a uniform random variable is $(1+50)/2=25.5$.
